# unknown input name check

Tags: php, input

How can I check the inputs below:

```
<?php 
  for($i = 0; $i < 9; $++){
echo "<input type='text' name='{$i}[qty]'>";
}
?>
```

now my qustion is how can I check the unknown input name if the value is bigger than 10 or smaller than 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did explain too little about your usage or the rest of your form structure. But generally you don't want to name the fields not with a number first, but the other way around:

```
print "<input type='text' name='qty[$i]'>";
   // would also work with just 'qty[]' in most cases
```

This way it becomes a very simple indexed array upon receival in PHP which you can traverse with:

```
$_REQUEST["qty"][$i++]
   // or
foreach ($_REQUEST["qty"] as $i => $qty) {
```

This way you wont miss either larger indexes than 10 or those below 0 - although you really should avoid negative indexes. (Not because it doesn't work, but it's probably an unoptimal methodology.)

---

If you use these `qty` form fields of part of another group, then you want to use the same `array[$i]` naming for all of them. Thus when you `foreach` over the loop you can access all in groups: `$_REQUEST["qty"][$i]` belongs to `$_REQUEST["product"][$i]` for example.

Comment: Good answer. You can do `<input type="text" name="qty[]" />` and PHP handles the index assignation. Good luck!